# DropKick Select Change event on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-dropkick

I am using the DropKick jQuery plugin. It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not in any IE browser. My JS is getting compiled and errors appear in vendor.js:

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
>       vendor.js?ver=1436779789, line 7560 character 9

Here is my code:

```
$('#teamDropdown').dropkick({
    change: function () {
        value = this.value;
        window.location.replace(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about a year later this has been fixed. :) Could it be possible you're using not the concatenated version? `dropkick.min.js` has polyfills for IE change events.